# Como criar um jogo multiplayer com bluetooth?

Tags: android, unity3d, bluetooth

Estou fazendo um game multiplayer no **Unity3D** e estou utilizando a nova API de networking do unity, já vi que existem alguns plugins para Unity que possibilitam a criação de um **multiplayer via bluetooth**, porém são pagos e relativamente caros.

Minha dúvida é se existe algum outro modo de criar um multiplayer para android via bluetooth de maneira gratuita utilizando o Unity?

Comment: Daniel, requisitar opinião e indicação de ferramentas é contra as regras do stack, da uma olhada no manual de ajuda http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask-beta e reformula a pergunta porque provavelmente será sinalizada como fora de escopo... Além disso vc pode pesquisar sozinho no google e vai encontrar muito material sobre APIs gratuitas e como usar os recursos do .NET 2.0 para comunicar em rede.

Comment: @Frohlich Acho se editar a pergunta para algo "Como fazer comunicacao de um jogo por bluetooth?" e tirar isto "de maneira gratuita" a pergunta ja fica dentro do escopo, mesmo nao sendo uma pergunta de tanta qualidade. Indicaria o google apenas para tutoriais de "meu primeiro jogo", nao sou muito a favor "procura no google" (apenas opiniao). Daniel recomendo que melhor um pouco a pergunta pra que ela se enquadre no escopo do site, eu pessoalmente achei a pergunta interessante.

Comment: Editei a resposta Daniel, mudou pouco.

Comment: Ok gente, obrigado. Acabei de ler o manual de ajuda "how to ask beta". Pelo que eu pesquisei cheguei à conclusão de que eu teria que criar um plugin ou adquirir um plugin já existente. Dada essas condições eu decidi que irei usar as ferramentas de networking que o Unity3D disponibiliza, pois já supre a minha necessidade. Obrigado.